# Function is broke after few loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to figured out the problem why my function is broken after few loops..

When i run my webpage its working fine but when i open another tab in my browser and let the function running and let it do for few loops and then back to that webpage the function is few times refreshing and after den the fadeout for background color start blinking but it be set up for 2000ms.. Any ideas for fix that ?

**I try to do this** : clear interval and run function again after every loop but it do same thing..

**Here is a sample** : [enter link here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbyVxP)

- Open the link and let function fully load then
- open another tab
- let function few times loop ( its set to 5 sec )
- back to the function

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mixit = $('#Container').mixItUp({
    load: {
      sort: 'random'
    },
    layout: {
      containerClass: 'list',
      display: 'block'
    }
  });

  function loop() {
    var arr = [];
    i = 0;
    $('.mix').each(function(){
      arr[i++] = $(this).data('myorder');
    });
    mixit.mixItUp('sort', 'random');

    mixit.on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
      var arr2 = [];
    i2 = 0;
    $('.mix').each(function(){
      arr2[i2++] = $(this).data('myorder');
    });
    for(i=0; i<i2; i++){
      for(j=0; j<i2; j++){
        if(arr[i]==arr2[j]){
          if(i<j){
            $('.mix').eq(j).css("background-color", "white");
          }
          if(i>j){
            $('.mix').eq(j).bgColorFade({
    time: 2000
});
          }
        }
      }
    }
    });
  };

  var looper = setInterval(loop, 5000);
});

$.fn.bgColorFade = function(mixcolor) {
    // starting color, ending color, duration in ms
    var options = $.extend({
      start: 'green',
        end: 'white',
      time: 2000
    }, mixcolor || {});
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor: options.start
    }).animate({
        backgroundColor: options.end
    }, options.time);
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is animation option `queue` (default: `true`) indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. To start animation immediately it should be set to `false`. The timers are not perfect (especially during switching tabs). Here the effects queue is not needed for color animation. It should start immediately. Disabling the queue (`queue: false`) fixes the animation:

```
$(this).css({
    backgroundColor: options.start
}).animate({
    backgroundColor: options.end
}, {
    duration: options.time,
    queue: false
});
```

---

The main reason for the broken animation is progressive registration of the `mixEnd` event handlers. The function `mixit.on('mixEnd', function(e, state){...})` should not be called inside the `loop` function, since during each call it registers a new handler function. So, the number of the even handler calls grows progressively with time. That was causing large queue for the animation effects.

So, if the callback is registered only once there is no problems: http://jsfiddle.net/1unLu3d4/3/

Comment: @Libor Zahrádka Your last code is broken, There are missing lines at the end: `return this; };`

Comment: @Libor Zahrádka There is another problem. The callback registration should be done only once before the loop function. That is the main bug. I updated the answer.